# Filter by array length or nested object property in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array with objects looking like that:

```
record in recordlist {
    date : "02/12/2014"
    time : "00.02.01"
    car : "369"
    pax: [
        {
        name : "Ben"
        chosen : true
        },
        {
        name : "Eric"
        chosen : true
        }
    ]
}
```

So far, when I list using ng-repeat, I'm able to filter by object (record) property.

**Filter:**

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Time" ng-model="search.time">
```

**ng-repeat:**

```
<div ng-repeat="record in filteredRecords = (recordlist | filter: search)">
```

The problem comes when I want to filter the nested array (**pax**). I've tried this, but so far no luck:

```
<input ng-model="search.pax.name"> // filter by name property

<input ng-model="search.pax.length"> // filter by array length
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to use a custom filter:

Something like this should do it:

```
<input ng-model="searchName">

<div ng-repeat="record in recordlist | filter: filterByNested">
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.filterByNested = function (record) {
    return record.pax.reduce(function (prev, curr, idx, array) {
        return prev || curr.name == $scope.searchName;
    }, false);
};
```

Basically you define a custom filter that returns true if the element you are searching is in the nested array.

It would be trivial to change the filter function to work based on length too.

Comment: Considering my example, in your function would be function(record) {return record.pax.reduce... ?

Comment: i've edited the answer for a better understanding, hope now it makes more sense.

Comment: So far is not working, the filter filters out all results (nothing listed) : /

Comment: Ok, maybe I was not clear on the question. I need exactly what your jsfiddle does, but the other way around! : ) So, the ng-repeat shows all results, and when the user types a name, the li elements not matching the filter input, disappear.

Comment: All you need to do then is revert the condition in the filter, I am not sure you are understanding how things work and it wouldn't be a good idea to use it without understanding it, but... here it is http://jsfiddle.net/tgddnc2p/1/

Comment: Still learning, I've been doing angular stuff for the last year, I don't have a tech background, everything takes forever to get properly understood, but I get there little by little : )